# Mouseup programmatically in Qt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, mouseup

#### Background

I'm building an application which runs in the background, and where the mouse cursor is moved programmatically into a dialog when the dialog "pops up". I have done this using [QCursor.setPos](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html#setPos)

#### Problem

The problem I'm having is that if the mouse button is pressed down when the user is interacting with something outside the application this might lead to unwanted things happening. For example if the user is changing the volume and the mouse is moved the volume might go to max or min

#### Question

**Is there any way (in Qt) to do a mouseup programmatically?**

If I do this before changing the position of the cursor it seems to me that there is less risk of problems (though there might be other problems resulting from this approach)

Comment: From what I understand, you want to disable the mouse click, or change its status. I am right?

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi and thank you for your question, i'd like to find a way to send mouseup so that when the mouse is moved (programmtically) there is no problem like with the example with the volume control. There might be other ways to solve the problem though and i'm open to ideas!

Comment: I could give you options if you provide a [mcve] since until now I do not understand what you want.

Comment: @eyllanesc It's not a code problem i'm having but thank you for wanting to help. I've updated the question in a couple of places and i hope this makes it more clear

Comment: With Qt it could be handled within the application since we can place an event filter, but outside it is difficult. For example, let's say that we have changed it a moment before, but when the mouse button stays pressed, the hardware will try to change its status and it will surely do so.

Comment: Note that this is not a trivial task. [`QCursor::shape`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html#shape) _may_ tell you something more about the current state.

Comment: Or you may fall back on OS specific stuff, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758202/getting-mouse-cursor-position-and-button-state-on-windows.